# Pygame documentation in Pycharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Pycharm allows to load external documentation sources in **Settings -> Python External Documentation**. I want to load Pygame documentation to get results similar to this:
[image]

I've tried to add it with following URL:

```
http://pygame.org/docs/ref/{module.name}.html#{element.qname}
```

however it's not working.

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Pygame.org requires https. Change `http://` to `https://` and you're ready to roll.